# How to hide this div class in the footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I hide this "Data tracking area" which is in the footer? This is the code. I'm on WordPress so I can't edit the CSS but add extra. I tried hiding it using the `display:none;` but did not work.

```
 <div id="footer" data-tracking-area="footer">
```

I tried this code but did not work.

```
.data-tracking-area{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: you want to remove `data-tracking-area` attribute that is specified in the HTML? Is that what you need?

Comment: You created a lot of different CSS questions and don't want to learn basics of CSS and HTML. But you want others to do work instead of you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add following css

```
#footer{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You`re right. But if topic-starter wants to remove something completely he'd better remove it from the HTML code, not just hiding by CSS. I think that question is not about the right point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector. Like this:

```
[data-tracking-area="footer"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Linking your CSS styles to data-attributes is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Attribute selectors are case-sensitive, and are written inside
>   brackets [].
>
> There are seven different types of matches you can find with an
>   attribute selector, and the syntax is different for each. Each of the
>   more complex attribute selectors build on the syntax of the exact
>   match selector — they all start with the attribute name and end with
>   an equals sign followed by the attribute value(s), usually in quotes.
>   What goes between the attribute name and equals sign is what makes the
>   difference among the selectors.

```
[data-tracking-area] {
/* Attribute exists */
}

[data-tracking-area="footer"] {
/* Attribute has this exact value */
}

[data-tracking-area=*"footer"] {
/* Attribute value contains this value somewhere in it */
}

[data-tracking-area=~"footer""] {
/* Attribute has this value in a space-separated list somewhere */
}

[data-tracking-area=^"footer"] {
/* Attribute value starts with this */
}

[data-tracking-area=|"footer"] {
/*Attribute value starts with this in a dash-separated list */
}

[data-tracking-area=$"footer"] {
/* Attribute value ends with this */
}
```

Here a basic example:

```css
[data-tracking-area="footer"]{
  height: 50px;
  background: green;  
}

[data-tracking-area*="foo"]{  
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-tracking-area$="footer"]{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" data-tracking-area="footer">select me by atrtibute selector</div>
```

You can use the one that best suits your needs.

Docs: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

Answer (score 0):

You can provide styling inline too. As below:

```
 <div id="footer" data-tracking-area="footer" style="display:none;">
```

Try this, hope gonna work.